# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Big(\frac{k}{n}\Big)^{\alpha k}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\alpha$ be a positive number. Calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Big(\frac{k}{n}\Big)^{\alpha k}$$

Edit: I have deleted my attempt, it didn't seem to lead me anywhere and I discovered a couple of mistakes. :)

Please give me a hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the sum as : $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{\alpha(n-k)}$$
Using Taylor series we have $$\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{\alpha(n-k) }=\exp\left(\alpha(n-k) \ln \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)\right) =e^{-\alpha k} -\frac{a k^2e ^{-\alpha k}}{2n} +o\left(\frac{a k^2e ^{-\alpha k}}{n} \right) $$
Because the sum of $ak^2 e^{-\alpha k}$ converges we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{a k^2e ^{-\alpha k}}{2n} +o\left(\frac{a k^2e ^{-\alpha k}}{n} \right)  =0$$
The the limit is $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{- \alpha k}= \frac{e^{\alpha}}{e^{\alpha}-1} $$

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Could you please explain the first line, how it is equivalent to the summation?

Comment: Yes indeed, very nice. Thanks :-)

Comment: In your Taylor series equations there's no $\alpha$ in the left hand side but there is in the right hand side?  Also the $o(1/n)$ term is not sufficient since it also depends on  the unbounded parameter $k$.  That's like saying that $k^2/n^2 = o(1/n)$ to conclude that $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2/n^2 \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @aziiri It should be $+\frac{a k^2e ^{-\alpha k}}{2n}$. How do you explain that
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}o\left(\frac{a k^2e ^{-\alpha k}}{n} \right)\to 0$? This is trivial if the final index of the sum does not depend on $n$, but this is not the case...